# Re-enable Skype 7.x in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, skype

How can I get Skype 7.x to work on Windows 10? It's currently disabled and will not work anymore, forcing me to "downgrade" to 8.x or the "Modern" Windows app. If I do this, I will no longer be able to reliably maintain a great history, or use an external database app to easily query past messages.

Comment: Why are you not posting the answer in the answer section? Answer it yourself as an answer, not as part of the actual question

Answer (score 13):

I found what seems to be a solution at http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/how-to-turn-off-the-skype-update-notifications/td-p/903552/page/2 ...

1) Redownload the SkypeSetup.exe file for the current version of Skype you wish to use/have installed

2) Navigate to the temp folder with the SkypeSetup.exe that updates to the newest version every time you start Skype

3) Delete SkypeSetup.exe, and replace it with the setup file for the current version of Skype you desire

4) Before you start Skype again, make sure to right click the SkypeSetup.exe file you have planted in the Temp folder, check Read-only, and hit apply

-This locks the file from being updated by Skype when you start it, and also takes the place of the Setup file Skype tries to force you to download-

5) Start Skype

Answer (score 5):

This still works for my Skype 7.34.66

1. Close your Skype.
2. Find this folder (or press Win + R [Run] and type `%Temp%`):

   `C:\Users\(your user name)\AppData\Local\Temp\`
3. Find file `SkypeSetup.exe`
4. Replace it with empty file (or you can open it with prefered text editor and wipe all text) and mark it with attribute `Read Only`.
5. Start your Skype as usual.

Tip: in file "Properties" -> "Security" deny "full access" for your user - it will guaranteed for asking permission before deleting (sometimes I clean this folder and delete it accidentally)

Answer (score 0):

This method below fixed it for me where the file name SkypeSetup.exe in the %temp% directory did not exist (was elsewhere named Skype-Setup.exe).

### Instructions to prevent/remove the Skype 'update warning popup'

Download your prefered Skype version. www.skaip.org/skype-versions

Uninstall any previous versions of Skype.

Restart your machine 'Offline' (no internet connection).

Install your prefered Skype version.

Goto Skype Tools, Options & turn off Automatic Updates.

Goto windows 'Services' & disable 'Skype Updater' service.

.............................................................

(My version is Skype 7.38.*.* on Windows 7)

Goto :-

C:\Users\(your user name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop

Rename file  Skype-Setup.exe  to something like  Skype-Setup-Original.exe

Create a new file in that directory using a text editor of some kind (like notepad)

Add random content to that new file (like the line below) & save as Skype-Setup.exe

22 44 66 22 44 66 22 44 66 Etc Etc Etc

RightClick the new Skype-Setup.exe file (in file manager/windows explorer) & change Properties to 'Read Only'

.............................................................

Restart your machine normally 'Online' (with internet connection).

Comment: Why add content to placeholder exe? Can't be a blank file? And why?

Comment: You "probably" could put any file there.  However, I think their algorithm checks the version to determine if the versions match and an update is needed.  A bogus file could trigger alternate action--forcibly overwrite the file, etc.  It all depends on which program is checking, and the power/rights of that program--user/admin/system.  See my answer above though and you will see that any 7.x solution will now be moot.

Answer (score -1):

How to disable Skype Update service:

1. Click Start
2. Run
3. Type services.msc (or run it in whatever manner you like)
4. Find SKYPE UPDATER
5. Right click Skype Updater
6. Properties
7. Startup type
8. Disabled