# Skype 7.40; Remove Home Screen Notification; This version of Skype will be discontinued

Tags: windows-7, skype, administrator, user-interface

Just have followed all instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/909367/prevent-skype-popup-asking-to-upgrade-in-2018) and prevented Skype 7.40 from updating or popping up with please update notices.

Would like remove the home screen which still asks for upgrade; here is a screen shot of what I mean;

[Screen Shot Of Skype Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNkIC.png)

A) Remove the home screen to something else
B) Remove Skype Home Completley
C) Get skype to open to a contact instead of home.

My Grandfather is 92, and while he uses the net and skype a bit, I really trying to make this ease for him.

Any help would be great. I can remote update his computer if Microsoft ever discontinues it, but they would be very silly to do so before making the new version much better.

Peace, MK

Comment: You do understand that eventually (very short amount of time) the version your asking about will no longer connect to the Skype network? The warning is there to inform you of this fact.  You might have to accept what you want simply isn’t possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going back to Skype 7.40 and unchecking Auto-updates.
This was the last version on which this was possible.
I also don't believe that Microsoft will dare block the classical
Skype any time soon.

Version 7.40.0.151 can be downloaded from
[skaip.org](http://www.skaip.org/skype-7-40-0-151-for-windows/download),
the unofficial website blog of Skype.
This is a well-known website, but for good measures I have tested this file
on VirusTotal
([report here](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/b442396895134bc2a1587e5875da664f13d68721fb6b707b328bc55bff39a45a/detection))
and it came out clean.

Turning off auto-update is said to be done this way (can't check myself):

- Sign in to Skype
- In the menu bar, select *Tools > Options....*
- In the *Advanced* tab, select *Automatic updates*
- Click *Turn off automatic updates*
- Click *Save*.

In Skype version 7.41, this option was removed.