# How to run old good classic Skype 7.41.0.101 after January 2019?

Tags: windows-10, skype, skype-for-windows-10

Until recently, it was possible to refuse Microsoft's offers to update ***Skype 7.41.0.101*** to version ***8.X***.

But since today, when I try to run ***Skype 7*** on ***Windows 10***, it starts for just a few seconds, then closes and pops up a window that offers to either update it to the 'crippled' ***Skype 8***, or exit it.
All the methods published in [Prevent Skype popup asking to upgrade? (In 2019)](https://superuser.com/questions/909367/prevent-skype-popup-asking-to-upgrade-in-2019/) are no longer working.

**Does anyone know what to do?**

I don't want to upgrade to **Skype 8** or downgrade to earlier unsafe versions of **Skype** prior **7.41**)*

Some background:

- On my second computer, the same version of Skype with the same account had worked 3 days longer before the mandatory update requirement appeared. On my third computer, the same version of Skype still continues to work fine.
- An old version 7.36 with disabled updates continues to run fine everywhere.
- Apparently, the problem is caused by a forced update of the Skype's update checker. This may explain the non-simultaneous occurrence of the problem on different computers.

Comment: login with Skype classic does not work any longer. but i was able to export my chats from C:\Users\\*\AppData\Roaming\Skype\\*\main.db with "Skyperious"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow instructions [here](https://www.winytips.com/download-skype-classic-7-41-101-7-40-104/). Install 7.36 first, then upgrade to 7.41.

*Update:*
You should disable the 7.41 update feature in the following way:

- Replace Skype8 installer from `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\SkypeSetup.exe` by installer of Skype7.
- Make file read-only and deny access of your user to this file (requires admin rights).

Comment: I will try it --- it has been reported that 7.36 does indeed work, and upgrading from there would likely RE-intorduce the problem -- but, maybe not.

Comment: I've tried this method. **7.36** works well (unless you pay attention to security issues), but version **7,41** still not work after re-upgrade (at least on my PC) :(

Comment: I suggested the use of 7.36 a few days ago and was told it didn’t work.  I would have submitted an answer if someone confirmed it did work.

Comment: @Ramhound, 7.36 itself works (I wrote it in my question!), but no one wants to use this version today (because of security issues), so in all instructions installing 7.36 is used only as first step before upgrading to 7.41. In the beginning of January 2019 it was possible to upgrade 7.36 to 7.41 and use it without any problems, but today 7.41 doesn't work after such upgrade (after start it demands either an upgrade to 8.x or an exit). So installing of 7.36 is not a solution :(

Comment: Must have been a different author to their question, about this issue, that indicated that 7.36 doesn't work.  It sounds like staying on 7.36 is a solution, if you don't want to upgrade to Skype 8.  *Some problems don't always have solutions that are secure.*

Comment: @IvanOlshansky I updated my solution and added section how to make 7.41 not to ask for update.

Comment: @AlexMaystrenko, present version of **Skype 8** doesn't create file %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\SkypeSetup.exe (at least on my system), so it's impossible to replace it :(

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Skype8 you have to remove completely! Installer is created by Skype 7.41 (but it is installer for skpye 8, ie it will run if you click upgrade).

Comment: @AlexMaystrenko, If it will be installer for **Skype 8**, where can I get installer for **Skype 7** to replace it with? But in any way on my system I haven't found file %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\SkypeSetup.exe after **Skype 7.41** install, so I can't check what kind of file it should be :( Have you tried this method by yourself?

Comment: @IvanOlshansky use link provided in my answer to download skype7. Yes this method works for me.

Comment: @AlexMaystrenko, I will accept your answer, although I have no way to verify it now. Let's hope it will help other users.

Comment: Got a link to the security problem for 7.36.0.101 ??  Seems like this version is the only viable answer, (unless that "security problem" is VERY severe with probable harm).  The V-8 from others I know, report not knowing if you even received a message, so my messages are never delivered in a meaningful way.   Although my Q with the Answer for installing a good working 7.36 was removed for not following SE Q/A format, it is still available in the last archive of that question.  I just don't have time to make it available "properly", anymore, until I post it on another forum.